# Laravel Logging to Slack via a Proxy

Tags: php, laravel, slack

I have configured my Laravel app running the Laravel 5.7.5 PHP Framework to send error notifications to a Slack channel. A snippet of my config/logging.php file looks as follows:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => (env('APP_ENV') == 'production') ? ['single', 'slack'] : ['single'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'error',
    ],
```

This works fine when I'm connected to the public internet (not via a proxy server), but my production servers need to send the requests via a Squid proxy server, and the requests are timing out.

How do I go about specifying a proxy server for the Slack Webhook to ensure that my requests are routed through the proxy server and get sent to the Slack API?

Comment: I think you might want to look on the configuration of your proxy server. Incoming webhooks use standard HTTPS requests using the same port and protocol like a HTTPS website. It looks to me that those might be blocked by your proxy. Can you access a normal HTTPS website from your machine? In general all client related proxy configuration needs to be done on your local client. Its not a Slack thing.

Comment: HTTPS requests aren't blocked by the proxy, I am able to successfully access HTTPS enabled sites through the proxy, but I don't know how to configure Laravel to send the webhooks to the Slack API via the proxy, so the connection to the API is timing out because they aren't being routed via the proxy server, and the firewall doesn't allow direct connections to the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that quite a lot of time has passed, but I ran into a similar problem, perhaps the material found may be useful to someone.

Judging by the source code of the library
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/SlackWebhookHandler.php

Currently, the current implementation cannot specify a proxy.

But you can define a custom-type logger.
Here in this article is written in detail how to do it.
https://medium.com/binarcode/laravel-5-6-custom-monolog-channel-to-store-logs-in-mariadb-23da52f537e7

I did it like this:

```
//config/logging.php
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'custom'),
....
'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => App\Extensions\SlackCustomLogger::class,
        'level' => 'debug',
        'url' => env('SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
    ],
...

<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

use Monolog\Logger;

class SlackCustomLogger
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Monolog\Logger
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $logger = new Logger('custom');
        $logger->pushHandler(new CustomSlackLogHandler(
            $config['url'],
            $config['channel'] ?? null,
            $config['username'] ?? 'Laravel',
            $config['attachment'] ?? true,
            $config['emoji'] ?? ':boom:',
            $config['short'] ?? false,
            $config['context'] ?? true,
            $config['level'] ?? 'debug'
        ));
        return $logger;
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Extensions;


use Monolog\Handler\Curl\Util;
use Monolog\Handler\SlackWebhookHandler;

class CustomSlackLogHandler extends SlackWebhookHandler
{
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        $postData = $this->getSlackRecord()->getSlackData($record);
        $postString = json_encode($postData);

        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getWebhookUrl(),
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postString
        );

        if(getenv('PROXY', false)) {
            $options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = getenv('PROXY');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, getenv('PROXY_PORT'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, getenv('PROXY_USERPWD'));
        }

        if (defined('CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD')) {
            $options[CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD] = true;
        }

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        Util::execute($ch);
    }
}
```